# Thread dies occassionally

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am running a background process that polls a file every 0.25 secs and if it finds required text runs a function. The thread dies out after a while and I am not sure if I am using this right

When left idle i.e., file doesn't have required text for a while, the thread dies out and doesn't work as expected when invoked (required text is written again into the file).

```
background_thread = Thread(target=main_task_thread, args=(...))
background_thread.start()
#background_thread.join()

def main_task_thread(...):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.25)
        with open('check.csv', 'r') as checkfile:
            checkdata = checkfile.readlines()[0]
        if "required_text" in check_data:
            lock.acquire()
            main_task(...)
            lock.release()


def main_task(...):
.
.
.
```

I have tried `background_thread.join()` but doesn't do anything since background thread is an infinite loop and never ends.

Is above the right way to have a background thread running that executes `main_task` whenever it finds required text in `checkfile`?

Comment: No exception handling?

Comment: Try wrapping all the statements in the `while true:` loop in a `try` / `except Exception as exc: print(exc)`.